# Any class in C# that can tell me clock tick, seconds consumed by a function

Tags: c#, seconds

Is there a class in C# that can give me clock ticks, seconds consumed by a method? I guess I have two wrap that functionality around function to time the ticks and seconds taken up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

// Your method call here...

sw.Stop();

// Get the elapsed time
TimeSpan elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
```

From here, you can use the [`TimeSpan.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) or the [`TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx) properties to determine the elapsed ticks or elapsed seconds, respectively.

If you wanted to, you could use a method along the following lines to "wrap" that functionality around a function, as you mentioned (just an idea, you'd probably want to tweak this code to suit your specific purposes -- passing in arguments, etc.):

```
public static T ExecuteWithElapsedTime<T>(Func<T> function, out TimeSpan elapsedTime)
{
   T rval;

   Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
   sw.Start();
   rval = function();
   sw.Stop();
   elapsedTime = sw.Elapsed;

   return rval;
}
```

And you could call it like this (where `myFunc` is a function that returns an `int`):

```
TimeSpan elapsed;
int result = ExecuteWithElapsedTime(myFunc, out elapsed);
```

Might be simpler though to not even bother with a method like this, and just put the Stopwatch code inline with your method call.

Comment: You got it :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
DoYaThing();
Console.WriteLine("{0} Elapsed", sw.Elapsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the [high resolution timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964692%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ...

Also, iirc a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can give you a measurement in ticks back.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `[System.TimeSpan]` class and wrap that around your method.